# how do i edit "unknown publisher" in my app?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

i guess my .NET application needs to be signed or something. how do i get rid of that prompt unknown publisher when someone tries to install my app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's the prompt I'm thinking of, you'd start by getting a certificate from someone like Verisign and use their certificate to sign your assembly.

You may be able to do a self-signed assembly using the information from these pages:

http://weblogs.asp.net/fbouma/archive/2003/12/23/45396.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247123(VS.80).aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/junfeng/archive/2006/03/11/549355.aspx

I'd recommnd reading up and going from there.

Comment: how much would it cost for verisign to do it?

Comment: It's not cheap.  Here is the link to their site where you can view the different prices.

http://www.verisign.com/code-signing/index.html?sl-hppd